# Execute command in PHP returns error code 127

Tags: php, system, execute

I am trying to execute cs2cs command for converting data format. But it always returns error code 127

Here is the code snippet:

```
$r = system('echo "830404.55 810145.46" | cs2cs +init=epsg:2326 +to +init=epsg:4326 -f %.10f', $result);
//$r = system('sh /var/www/html/et/test.sh', $result); // returns error code 127
echo $r.'<br>'; // print nothing
echo $result.'<br>'; // print 127
```

1. It is OK when I execute `'echo "830404.55 810145.46" | cs2cs +init=epsg:2326 +to +init=epsg:4326 -f %.10f'` with command line in Linux system.
2. It is OK when I execute `'/var/www/html/et/test.sh'` with command
   line in Linux system.

Any idea of why it happens? I am not sure it is problem with **PHP** or **cs2cs**. I think it may caused by cs2cs cannot be executed by apache user account. If it is the case, how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Seems that your apache user has no permission to execute the command

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if I use the full path of cs2cs:

```
$r = system('echo "830404.55 810145.46" | /usr/bin/cs2cs +init=epsg:2326 +to +init=epsg:4326 -f %.10f', $result);
```